# How to change the background in different colors of a cell when comparing dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to create some kind of automatic progress list in Excel 2010 with changing background cell colors according to dates in comparison with today.

Formatting of column B:

- When 'Executed Date' is filled in: always light yellow background
- When 'Executed Date isn't filled in:

  - Always light yellow background if today is earlier than 7 days before 'Target Date'
  - Orange background if today is less than 7 days before 'Target Date'
  - Red background if today is later than 'Target Date' (no execution date is given).

I hope this is better:

'If colom C is filled in (=job is done): always light yellow cell background of colom B

'If colom C isn't filled in (job isn't done):

if (today) < (target date-7 days): light yellow cell background of colom B

or if (today) =/> (target date-7 days): orange cell background of colom B

or  if (today) >(target date): red cell background of colom B

Sample Image below
[image: example scenario]

Comment: Use light yellow backcolor as default and 2 separate conditional formatting by-formula rules with orange and red backcolors in proper order.

Comment: May be I'm unable to simplify but the Criteria are quit confusing like, `earlier than 7 days before`,,,, !

Comment: I mean: if (today) < (target date-7 days). I hope it's more clear now. I'll change the attachement.

Comment: @YvesMadec if you can keep your explanation on the body of the text like I did, it would be much appreciated! :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this result, you need to add 4 Conditional formatting on the Column B using the following formula's in the **following Order**:

1. Executed Date is Filled: `=$C2<>""`
2. Executed Date not filled & (today) < (target date-7 days): `=AND($C2<>"",TODAY() < $B2-7)`
3. Executed Date not filled & (today) =/> (target date-7 days): `=AND($B2<>"",$C2<>"",TODAY()>=$B2-7)`
4. Executed Date not filled & (today) >(target date): `=AND($B2<>"", $C2<>"",TODAY()>$B2)`

**Note**: Please note that you need to add the conditonal formatting in the above order for them to work as expected.

Please find a sample excel file at the following link: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dZgthruWZIzQjUgbAaviCFSKJPHgpFvl

Working Example image: 
[image: Conditional Formatting]

**Resources**:
**Conditional Formatting**: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f